# apache + mod_wsgi + django +askbot

Tags: django, apache, askbot

> error:File does not exist:
>   /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/site_media/media/photos/3.jpg the real
>   address 3.jpg is at
>   /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/askbot/upfiles/photos/3.jpg

All apalication is run well as `python manage.py runserver`:

centos6.2 python2.7(/opt/python2.7.2)

**hpptd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin matt@360yuer.com
    ServerName www.360yuer.com
    DocumentRoot /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/apache/fenxiang.wsgi

    Alias /site_media/ /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/site_media/
    Alias /upfiles/ /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/askbot/upfiles/

    Alias /static/ /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/static/ 
    AddType text/html .py

    <Directory  /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/apache >
       Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/site_media>
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/askbot/upfiles>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

    <Directory /home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I am a newer, and I do not know how to fix it ,
the current problem is can not find the /askbot/upfiles/3.jpg, and some css in /static/css

**settings.py**

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(ASKBOT_ROOT, 'skins'), os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"), ASKBOT_EXTRA_SKINS_DIR)
 RECAPTCHA_USE_SSL = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
/askbot/upfiles/3.jpg
```

you should be using URL with:

```
/upfiles/3.jpg
```

in it. That is what you have Alias set up for.

As for CSS files, are they actually in the directory:

```
/home/WorkSpace/fenxiang/static/css/
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, the errors is so many, such as invalid image,I will reinstall centos.